# Java BigDecimal Round Down issue

Tags: java

I have some simple code to round up and round down, but it is producing some unexpected results.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double a = 46.66;
    System.out.println("Roundup: " + roundUp(a,2) + "\nRound Down: " + roundDown(a,2));

}

public static double roundUp(double a, int scale)
{
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(a);
    value = value.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.UP);
    return value.doubleValue();
}

public static double roundDown(double a, int scale)
{
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(a);
    value = value.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    return value.doubleValue();
}
```

When I use 3 digits after decimal, it is working as expected. If a = 44.661, the output is as expected as below.

Roundup: 46.67  Round Down: 46.66

When a=44.66, the round down value reduces by 1 which is unexpected as below.

Roundup: 46.66  Round Down: 46.65

How do I get 44.66 for round down and 44.67 for roundUp while still retaining the above results.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think the real question is "Why would `44.66` rounded to 2 decimals be different for `roundUp` or `roundDown`? It shouldn't round at all. Welcome to floating point arithmetic. Try changing all instances of double to BigDecimal and see what happens then :-)

Comment: do you really need it to be a BigDecimal?

Comment: Sednus, code is invoked by a packaged code that supports passing only basic types (double in this case). So I need to take an input as a double, and round it up or down to two digits. I might get something like 46.66 or 46.661 depending on the item price. Can this be done with just doubles without using BigDecimal?

Comment: @corsiKa, I can't really change all of them to BigDecimal since I need to pass in a double to this code.

Comment: @user1330714 I didn't mean use doubles for your actual task. I meant use doubles as an experiment to gain understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you're not really using BigDecimals, you're using doubles. When you type `44.66` it gets converted to a double, which results in a value slightly less than 44.66. `BigDecimal` can't fix rounding errors that have already occurred before you give it the input.

Try this instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("46.66");
    System.out.println("Roundup: " + roundUp(a,2) + "\nRound Down: " + roundDown(a,2));
}

public static BigDecimal roundUp(BigDecimal a, int scale)
{
    return a.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.UP);
}

public static BigDecimal roundDown(BigDecimal a, int scale)
{
    return a.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.DOWN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot use BigDecimal throughout, since this code is invoked by a packaged code that supports passing only basic types (double in this case). So I need to take an input as a double, and round it up or down to two digits. I might get something like 46.66 or 46.661 depending on the item price. Can this be done with just doubles without using BigDecimal?

Comment: You _cannot_ get exact decimal values with doubles.  46.66 will actually be 46.659999999999996589394868351519107818603515625, and there is _no_ way around that with `double`s.  (If the packaged code uses doubles to store prices...you should be yelling until they fix it.  That's about as big a no-no as it gets.)

Comment: Thanks @Antimony and @"Louis Wasserman" I didn't realize the true value of double when I use a=46.66. Thanks to your posts, I now do :). I finally used a workaround in the roundUp method as below.

BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(a + "");

Essentially I am using the constructor with String to get the value of 46.66 from the passed double value. That solved the issue. I know it is not optimal, but hey, passing the double value for price from packaged code is not a good thing either.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is round up or down using BigDecimal.valueOf

```
 BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(a);
```

This compensates for the representation error of doubles, however this may not be enough if you have some arithemtic rounding error as well.

Instead you need to determine what is the largest rounding error you can have

```
public static double roundUp2(double d) {
    return Math.ceil(d * 100 - ERR)/100.0;
}

public static double roundHalf2(double d) {
    return Math.ceil(d * 100)/100.0;
}

public static double roundDown2(double d) {
    return Math.floor(d * 100 + ERR)/100.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you really what you need is to do something like the following function:

```
private static void roundUp(double num, int decimalPlaces){

for (int i =0; i< decimalPlaces; ++i){
     num*=10; 
}

int tmp = (int) (num+0.5);
num = tmp;

for (int i =0; i< decimalPlaces; ++i){
     num = num/10; 
}
}
```

and you may use an alternate for rounding down where you just change the "num+0.5" for "num - 0.5".  Howver this might result troublesome when printed because of the machine floating number error.  But youe can work something out for that as well.